# CSS card rotate on hover not working in Safari

Tags: html, css

**EDIT** It seems that adding Bootstrap breaks the function. Assuming it's because I'm reusing the `card` class.

I have a `li` element that acts as a card, and "flips" over when hovered. It's working as expected in Google Chrome, JS Fiddle, and this stack overflow code snippet. When I view it in Safari the card "back" shows for a second and then disappears (turns all white).

Any ideas what's going on here? I'm wondering if it's the `backface-visibilty` property, but not sure how to resolve that?

```css
body{
  background-color: grey;
}

.card-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}

.card-wrapper .card {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card-wrapper .card .front,
.card-wrapper .card .back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    text-align: center;
}

.card-wrapper .card .front {
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

.card-wrapper .card .back,
.card-wrapper .card .back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-wrapper:hover .card,
.card-wrapper:hover .card {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-wrapper,
.card {
    width: 275px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.card .front,
.card .back {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.card .front {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.card .back {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<li class="card-wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      <br>
      <p>This is the front of the card</p>
    </div>
    <div class="back">This is the back of the card</div>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="card-wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      <br>
      <p>This is the front of the card</p>
    </div>
    <div class="back">This is the back of the card</div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on Safari 16.1; it seems to work as intended. What version of Safari are you testing with? Is the issue on iOS or desktop or both?

Comment: Safari 16.0 on Mac. Happens on iOS as well. I've tried adding -webkit to the transforms and backface-visibilty with no luck. I also have the issue if I use the Google Chrome app on an iPhone.

Comment: I’m on Safari 16.3 on Ventura 13.2.1, and your snippet works perfectly for me. Also tested on iOS 16.3.1 and works perfectly there as well.

Comment: I also discovered that a long tap in iOS Safari triggers the `:hover` state, which I didn’t know before, so thanks!

Comment: @Yolo_chicken Chrome on the iPhone uses Webkit, which is the same browser engine as Safari, and why they behave identically. Just to make sure, are you seeing this issue in the Stack Overflow snippet as well, or just locally? And if possible, can you link a quick video or GIF of the issue on your end?

Comment: I implemented a similar animation in the past on https://tintgenerator.vercel.app/. Does the animation work properly for you there?

Comment: So adding the webkit in isolation fixes the issue, but not in my project. So there must be something impacting the styles that I'm not aware of. Will post the answer when I figure it out.

Comment: See post edit, I think I found the culprit. Realized I was using a `card` class name, which bootstrap uses and I'm using bootstrap. Will work on a fix now.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the reason was because I was using Bootstrap and named these elements with the `card` class name - interfering with Bootstrap. What I don't know is, why would this happen in Safari but not Google. Either way, it's fixed. Thanks to the comments above.

```css
body{
  background-color: grey;
}

.card-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}

.card-wrapper .cardx {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card-wrapper .cardx .front,
.card-wrapper .cardx .back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    text-align: center;
}

.card-wrapper .cardx .front {
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

.card-wrapper .cardx .back,
.card-wrapper .cardx .back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-wrapper:hover .cardx,
.card-wrapper:hover .cardx {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-wrapper,
.cardx {
    width: 275px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.cardx .front,
.cardx .back {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.cardx .front {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.cardx .back {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<li class="card-wrapper">
  <div class="cardx">
    <div class="front">
      <br>
      <p>This is the front of the card</p>
    </div>
    <div class="back">This is the back of the card</div>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="card-wrapper">
  <div class="cardx">
    <div class="front">
      <br>
      <p>This is the front of the card</p>
    </div>
    <div class="back">This is the back of the card</div>
  </div>
</li>
```